# ¿Como realizar un script en C++ que me muestre códigos de CMD?

Tags: c++, cmd

Tengo un script en C++ que me deja usar comandos de CMD pero quisiera saber cómo mostrar algún comando al momento de compilar el script.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
    using namespace std;
    void cmd()
    {
       while (true) 
    {

    cout <<"comando:";
    string comando;
    getline(cin,comando);
    system(comando.c_str());
    if(comando=="exit") break;
    }
    }
    int main (int argc,char * argu [])
    {
        cmd();
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: No puedes hacer scripts en [tag:c++] ya que es un lenguaje compilado, no interpretado.

Comment: Si intentas crear un terminal, revisa [este repositorio](https://github.com/jupyter-xeus/cpp-terminal)